# How to send SQL Server data between servers with SQLAlchemy while maintaining the character set?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, unicode, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've been trying to copy an entire db from one remote sql server to a local server. Due to the limited access, I have to do so using a python script.

The remote data contains tables that has columns with Arabic values, where the collation is set to: **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**

I've been trying to do that with the entire tables using sqlalchemy and row by row with pyodbc.

When the Arabic data is read in python, it's correctly represented (as Arabic characters), and I'm assuming they're being converted/read as utf8. However, the same values would then be parsed as question marks once they are sent to the local database.

After further diagnosing, I noticed that even when inserting Arabic values locally on our database, it would be converted to question marks, although the collation is set to **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**. So, I've, locally, tried to change that to **Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS** then manually insert some values, which did work.

Nonetheless, now that I need to use the script to transfer the data, the collation setup would automatically change once the new values are inserted.

I've tried to change the setting within the engine and connection link with no luck. Here is the code for my work in sqlalchemy:

```
import codecs
import sys
import urllib
import time
import sqlalchemy as sal
import pandas as pd
import contextlib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import pyodbc

# SETTING UP THE CONNECTIONS ------------------------------------------------------------------------!

remoteServer = 'IP'
remoteDatabase = 'dbo'
remoteTrusted_Connection = 'yes'

localServer = 'IP'
localDatabase = 'dbo'
localUID = 'user'
localPWD = 'pass'

conArgs = {'init_command':"SET @@collation_connection='Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS'"}

remoteParams = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + remoteServer + ';DATABASE=' + remoteDatabase + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;'
remoteURLib = urllib.parse.quote_plus(remoteParams)
remoteEngine = sal.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s?charset=utf8" % remoteURLib, connect_args=conArgs)

remoteInspect = sal.inspect(remoteEngine)
remoteConn = remoteEngine.connect()

localParams = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + localServer + ';DATABASE=' + localDatabase + ';UID=' + localUID + ';PWD=' + localPWD + ';'
localURLib = urllib.parse.quote_plus(localParams)
localEngine = sal.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s?charset=utf8" % localURLib, connect_args=conArgs)

localInspect = sal.inspect(localEngine)
localConn = localEngine.connect()

remoteTableNames = remoteInspect.get_table_names()

# HERE IS WHERE THE DATA MOVING HAPPENS ------------------------------------------------------------------------!

totalTime = time.time()

for index, tableName in enumerate(remoteTableNames):
    thisTime = time.time()
    print(f'This is table #{index}: {tableName}')

    tableData = pd.read_sql(tableName, remoteConn)
    tableData.to_sql(tableName, localEngine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    print(f'Completed {tableName} in {time.time() - thisTime:.1f} seconds')

print()
print(f'Done - it took {time.time() - totalTime:.1f} seconds')

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!

remoteConn.close()
localConn.close()
```

Comment: Collations are configured at both the database level and column levels. The database's default collation is used for scalar string operations, but individual columns can be set to entirely different collations (even different collations from one another). How have you determined what the collations were in the source database and columns? Are you sure that the source columns were of `char` or `varchar` type - and not `nchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: Aside... `@@collation_connection` is a MySQL-ism. Are you even dealing with Microsoft SQL Server here?

Comment: I checked the collation on a columns level, and you're right. Indeed, not all columns have this setup, and it's only set to columns with types varchar and nvarchar.

About the @@collation_connection, I'm actually not a db guy, and you can consider me as a beginner in the world of development. I've borrowed this call from another thread which as you mentioned is for MySQL, I was just trying things!

Comment: Why not use NVARCHAR and forget the collation stuff

Comment: Even when using `nchar` and `nvarchar` data types collations are still used for equality comparisons (and grouping) as well as sort ordering. But, yes, you'll have a much easier time with international characters if you migrate away from `char` and `varchar` data types.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with using `.to_sql(…, if_exists="replace")` is that the default settings don't give you control over the collation of the columns; they will be whatever the database default is. However, you could create the destination table first,

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

source_engine = sa.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@192.168.0.199/test"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
)
dest_engine = sa.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@192.168.0.100/test"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"
)

table_name = "so75801426"
tbl = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=source_engine)
tbl.drop(dest_engine, checkfirst=True)
dest_engine.echo = True
tbl.create(dest_engine)
"""DDL emitted:
CREATE TABLE so75801426 (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    txt VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Ukrainian_CP1251_CI_AS NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_so75801426] PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
"""
```

and then it *should* be as simple as using something like

```py
with dest_engine.begin() as conn:
    df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists="append", …)
```

to copy the rows.

However, due to a pandas issue reported 2.5 years ago (August 2020)

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35627

that fails because the text values get sent to SQL Server with non-latin1 characters replaced by question marks. For example, with a DataFrame like

```py
print(df)
"""
   id   txt
0   1  друг
"""
```

the SQL Server receives

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 varchar(max)',
  N'INSERT INTO so75801426 (id, txt) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',1,'????'
```

As a workaround, we can use `dtype=` to have `.to_sql()` send strings as Unicode if the target column is a string type

```py
insp = sa.inspect(dest_engine)
col_info = insp.get_columns(table_name)
dtype_dict = {
    ci["name"]: sa.Unicode
    for ci in col_info
    if isinstance(ci["type"], (sa.VARCHAR, sa.NVARCHAR))
}
print(dtype_dict)
# {'txt': <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.Unicode'>}

with dest_engine.begin() as dest_conn:
    df.to_sql(
        table_name,
        dest_conn,
        if_exists="append",
        index=False,
        dtype=dtype_dict,
    )
```

so SQL Server receives

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 nvarchar(max)',
  N'INSERT INTO so75801426 (id, txt) VALUES (@P1, @P2)',1,N'друг'
```

and it can convert the Unicode back to the original (SBCS) character set.

Note also that SQLAlchemy is not really intended to be a replacement for a dedicated database-migration tool.

Comment: When I try using your approach I get the "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object" error. This is due to the fact that the engine is reading the Arabic letters as question marks, and when ever two words are of the same length this could happen.

And you're right that SQLAlchemy is not meant for such use specially that there are database-migration tools. However, the situation here is a bit complicated.